# Access component property in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a react component similiar to bootstrap component ListGroup that looks like this:

```
import ListGroup from react-bootstrap

<ListGroup>
  <ListGroup.Item></ListGroup.item>
  <ListGroup.Item></ListGroup.item>
  <ListGroup.Item></ListGroup.item>
</ListGroup>
```

I've tried to do this:

```
class ListGroup extends Component {
  Item = () => {
    return <div>Item</div>
  }

  render() {
    return <div>List</div>
  }
```

But when i try to use it in another file, it gives me an error (ListGroup.Item undefined). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is ultimately what you're looking for:

Using "Class Component":

```
class ListGroup extends Component {

    static Item = (props) => {
        return <div>{props.children}</div>;
    };

    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
}

export default ListGroup;
```

Using "Functional Component":

```
import React from 'react';

const ListGroup = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

ListGroup.Item = (props) => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

export default ListGroup;
```

wherever youre calling it:

```
<ListGroup>
    <ListGroup.Item>Custom Txt</ListGroup.Item>
</ListGroup>
```

Comment: thank you, that works fine, but is there a way to do the same thing by using arrow function instead of class to create component?

Comment: const ListGroup = ({ children }) => {
  const Item = ({ children }) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
  };

  return <div>{children}</div>;
};